# It is ok to hate a company that did not reschedule a interview?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, human-resources

A person look for me on Linkedin asking if I would be interest in a oportunity. She worked at the HR department in a Software Development company. When she send me the salary I get very interested. So I sent to her my CV and she schedule a simple interview with me. I went to that interview and she said to me that a technical challenge would be sent to me. Later in the same day, I started to solve the task, but even before I finished the challenge she sent me a message saying that her manager get very interested in my profile and asked for me if I could do a interview with him. I said yes and kept doing the challenge.

The problem is that I was so focused on the challenge that my tasks on my current company accumulated. Also, my team is in a very bad situation. So I thought that would no be fair with my current company and with my team mates simply not appear on my hour of work and going to the interview. So I sent her a message 4 hours before the interview saying that would not be possible to me to participate of the interview in that day and asked for reschedule. She said that would not be possible. I tried to insist, but she refused and saying that day would be the only one available. She replied me with the classic "We will save your CV with us!". But now I fell so much hate for this company. If they liked me so much why they could no reschedule? I know that I was wrong when I simply accept the interview invitation, but I just asked for a reschedule not to they built a rocket for me.

UPDATE: To make things clear. When I was on the first Interview, the woman said that the company was very comprehensive with hour. Also, they knew that I still on graduation, so I also have other issues to solve other than my professional life. Last, if they liked me so much, why they couldn't reschedule the interview for next day? Why this such a horrible things?

Comment: Whether or not it's "okay" to hate someone isn't really on topic for this site. Are you looking for answers about how to behave in the interviewing process? Or how to handle pushy recruiters? Or anything else concrete?

Comment: Well, I actually would like to have a "second chance". But if they come to look for me I'm feeling so much angry that I think that I would reject only for proud.

Comment: So what question would you like us to answer for you? The only question in your post is the title, and we can't tell you who to hate or not.

Comment: My question is, who is wrong in this history? Me, they or both?

Comment: Why was an interview task causing your work tasks to accumulate? That means either you're doing the interview task during work hours, or you're working overtime a lot, neither of which are good.

Comment: Because as I said, in the comment section in the answer of @385703, I work as a trainee, not a full job worker and I'm current at a graduation course in Computer Science and it is my final week in the semester, so I got lot of work accumulated.

Comment: Sounds like you had a chance and you blew it. You should learn from this not to cancel an interview at short notice, unless it is an emergency. A hiring company is not obligated to bend over backwards to accommodate your schedule.

Comment: I update the question, please check' out.

Comment: Keep in mind that hate hurts you, but rarely hurts the person or thing that's hated.  I would suggest a different approach, preferably one that involves learning something or at least forgetting and moving on.

Comment: Your update doesn't change anything. You made a choice to not prioritize their interview. Chances are, the hiring Manager is much busier than you are. The burden is on you to accommodate their schedule, not the other way around. They can just as well ask: "If this candidate wanted the job so much, why did they cancel the interview?"

Comment: Yes, you should definitely hate on the person.

Answer (score 18):

You don't cancel interviews with such a short notice unless you're sick or have experienced another important accident that made your participation objectively impossible (sickness in the family, cancelled flight, etc.).

By scheduling and cancelling because "your tasks at the current job accumulated" you showed them you are bad at planning and foreseeing the effects of your decisions and that you can't be counted on.

You are yourself to blame for the rejection. Of course, we all make mistakes. It's not the end of the world but try to learn from it.

Comment: Totally disgree. I currently work as trainee not as a full job worker and I'm on graduation course of Computer Sciente, so I had more tasks than my job.

Comment: The point is, you committed to a scheduled interview knowing all that (or knowing it was possible), and then changed your mind.

Comment: My concept for modern software development companies is that they are comprehensive and flexible with they schedules.

Comment: Their concern for candidates is that they are able to agree to a commitment and then stick with it, barring extreme unforeseeable circumstances.

Comment: @CelsoJunior You're free to disagree, but this answer is likely how the company sees it, and how many other companies will see it. To add to the answer: they can also see it as a sign that you don't respect them or their time (they may have lost out on that time they booked especially for you, because you decided you had better things to do).

Comment: To make things clear they knew that I'm under graduation and I have a lot of work to do from my course. They could be a little complacent don't you think?

Comment: @CelsoJunior *'They could be a little complacent don't you think? '* They could be, but they don't have to be. You may be confused by the transition from school to the workplace. Schools have to give at least lip service to caring about you and your personal development. Schools will generally cut you slack and provide lots of 2nd chances. The primary goal of most private employers is to make money. They offer benefits only insofar as employing you helps them solve their problems. The more problems you cause for them, the less likely they are to be interested in employing you.

Comment: I updated the question. Please check' out.

Answer (score 7):

> It is ok to hate a company that did not reschedule a interview?

No it's not. It's unprofessional, immature, and counterproductive.

Sometimes things work out, sometimes they don't. If they don't you should objectively analyze the situation and learn from it. In this case, you made a commitment (for an interview) and try to back out on short notice. That signals to the hiring company that you may be disorganized and not reliable, so they dug in and see what you would do. You still backed out and so they lost interest. Perfectly normal and smart behavior for a hiring manager.

You can certainly chose to "hate" the company, but what would you hope to gain or achieve from this? It would be much smarter to apologize to them "I'm sorry I had to cancel the interview on short notice, but an emergency came up at my current job that I really needed to handle". Maybe they buy it and you can leave the door open for future opportunities. If not, you are no worse off than you currently are

Professionals make decision with their brains and leave emotions out of it as much as possible. Don't get me wrong: it's great that you got excited about this new opportunity, but it seems you also got carried away and did not plan your approach properly.

Comment: Well, there are times when you use emotions effectively to get what you want. Of course, this is not one of those situations.

Comment: I updated the question. Please check' out.

Comment: @CelsoJunior: your update doesn't change anything. The fact is that you failed to deliver on an important commitment. The way they see it is probably: "If the guy isn't capable of managing a really important commitment like an interview, he probably can't manage regular day to day work at all". Of course they could have accomodated you but why should they? They probably liked your technical skills but were turned off by communication/organizational style. You need both for a decent job.